# Fail to connect to another Service that also runs in Azure

Tags: azure, dns

We are trying to use the API of another service that is also running in Azure. In our local environment, we can DNS resolve against api.example.com to their correct public IP address. it's https, and binding correctly.

But when we deploy, the api.example.com resolves on our azure servers, to their internal Azure address of 65.*.*.*

The SSL Cert Fails validation and the call times out because the SSL cert is bound to the public IP, not the internal IP 65. address.

How can I tell our Azure servers, making a service call to api.example.com using the public DNS, instead of Azure internal address?

Thank you for your help friends!

Comment: This is crazy! You say that a custom domain (non xx.cloudapp.net) is resolved to Azure private IP Address (direct IP, DIP) instead of the public one ? But 65.xxx.xxx.xx is **not** a private network Address. It is **public** addressable IP address. Are you sure the third party service does not run behind Traffic Manager, so you see it different when from office and from inside Azure DC ? or something like that ?

Comment: Also, when it turns out (you can check yourself) the 65.xxx.xx.xxxx is a public addressable IP Address, can you contact the third party service owners to resolve the issue. or at least to track it down. Because I am pretty sure 65.xxx.yyy.zzz is from a public range and if you query RIPE (or ARIN for Norh America) you will get Microsoft as owner.

Comment: Scott, if you resolved your issue please post and answer, mark as answer or just delete your question. Please do not leave questions hanging out.